# How do I successfully convert a markdown file to docx in APA format?

Tags: pandoc

​I'm having a difficult time exporting markdown to docx in APA format. I attached a file that shows my problem. The markdown file (byword) is my core writing, the middle file is what I get when I export to docx using marked 2 (when I use pandoc alone the export is horrendous - meaning the headings are different sizes, fonts, and colors) and the docx on the far right is what I want - typical APA format (I manually formatted it in Word). Any advice on how to accomplish this?

I will say, though, that I don't have these issues when I export from md to pdf using pandoc. PDF always exports itself beautifully, but my workflow **requires** docx.

So much thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome. I think this is off topic here, I'm afraid, as your question has nothing at all to do with (La)TeX. While we do have a pandoc tag, note that the tag description specifically says that questions about pandoc itself are off topic, but if it involves LaTeX conversion, then it's on topic.

Comment: I do not use Word a, but it seem that document structure is OK, and you only need change the default styles. It shoul ba an easy task, but this is off-topic here.  BTW, in the PDF the result is beautiful  because is exported to LaTeX.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your replies. I also apologize about this not being a LaTex specific question.